# Watching Stewie sleep and rubbing knife against face reference?

Tags: reference, family-guy

In the Family Guy episode about Stewie's play, there is a scene in which Brian sneaks into his room to steal the manuscript of the play and destroy it out of jealousy, and there is a strange man in the room who explains his presence by saying "I'm just the guy Stewie pays to watch him sleep... He just pays me to watch him sleep and rub a knife against my face."

[image]

Is this a reference to something?

Comment: I'm betting it's meant to be just some cliche serial killer move

Answer (score -2):

The short answer: No.  There were no movie or TV scenes that resembled this type of activity at the time the show was written.  Family Guy is known for left field imagery and scenes, like Peter's famous "Ssssssssssss!" sound when he bangs his knee on something, or the time he poked holes in the frog in a box "so it could breathe".  It's just another strange image that pushes that particular scene along.

Comment: There is no possible way for any single man to say that "There were no movie or TV scenes that resembled this type of activity at the time the show was written.". Have you seen all the movies or TV scenes in exitance?

Comment: Given that McFarlane uses references that are typically recognizable, I based my answer on about a dozen articles and responses to those articles.  If not a single person who wrote or responded to those articles mentioned any reference, when many of them mentioned that specific scene, it's pretty safe to say that it's not based on any known TV or movie scene.  Sometimes, that writing team just makes up stuff, as I mentioned in my answer.  If you can prove me wrong, feel free to do so.

Comment: I have no interest in proving you wrong. In fact, you may be very right. Nevertheless, that does not make you write as well! If you have a reference, please refer to it with a link. In any case, all such a reference can claim is "we have conducted a thorough researched but we could not find a referenced scene". That is the correct way to write such a statement. It states that I did not find one but a reference could exist.

Comment: The scene just seems so specific and idiosyncratic that it is hard to imagine it does not have some precedent.

Comment: And yet, 5 years later, no one has come up with one.  So....